# Laravel queue using supervisord ignoring tries limit

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, supervisord

I am running a laravel queue being monitored by Supervisord:

```
php /home/path/to/artisan queue:listen --env=production --timeout=0 --sleep=5 --tries=3
```

However if a job is failing, it is trying indefinitely - the 'count' in the jobs table shows 255 which is the max mysql field limit, but it has been doing thousands of attempts.

If the jobs table has 'attempts' marked at 255, and 'tries' set as 3 - why is it continuing to run this job in the queue?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `artisan queue:work --daemon` with supervisord, `listen` is used for development (always pick new code without restart), to understand the difference you can read the commands code.

Comment: Thanks for that - just to follow up now I'm back looking at this, I'm now using the following code, and still experincing the issue where it doesn't seem to ever put it into the failed job queue: 

`artisan queue:work --daemon --env=production --timeout=0 --sleep=5 --tries=3`

Comment: Show me how did you push a job into the queue

Comment: Just simply like this `$this->dispatch(new CompileForm($data));`